# Why am I getting in an infinite loop with this parent-child recursion?

Tags: php, recursion, tree, parent-child

I have the following two functions which should return a treeview-like dropdown.

PHP:

```
function getCategories()
{
    $src = $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM categories')->fetchAll();
    return $this->tree($src, 0, '');
}

function tree($src, $level, $html)
{
    $dashes = '';
    for($i=0;$i<$level;$i++)
    {
        $dashes .= '-';
    }

    foreach($src as $row)
    {
        if($row['parent'] == $level)
        {
            $html .= '<option value="'. $row['id'] .'">'. $dashes . $row['name'] .'</option>';
        }
    }

    $html .= $this->tree($src, $level + 1, $html);

    return $html;
}
```

Expected HTML result:

```
<option value="1">Category1</option>
<option value="2">-Category2</option>
<option value="3">--Category3</option>
<option value="4">-Category4</option>
```

But it leads to an infinite loop instead. Why?

Comment: Debug your code and you will get to know.

Comment: Well, you don't have any return condition. *Every* call to `tree` will unconditionally result in another call to `tree`, which will result in another call to `tree` etc.

Comment: Ahh yes, now I see the problem. Thanks, @deceze

Answer (score 1):

Every recursion must have a [base case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29). A point where the recursion stops.

At the moment you unconditionally do a recursive call, so naturally, you'll get an infinite recursion.